# neocomplete error when using latest spf13-vim

Tags: macvim, plugin-neocomplete, plugin-spf13

I have been using spf13-vim for a while now. Recently I have upgraded by pulling down master from GitHub repo. After the updates I see that spf13-vim has neocomplete enabled by default.
One of the settings in ***~/.vimrc.bundles*** is as following:

```
if !exists('g:spf13_bundle_groups')
        let g:spf13_bundle_groups=['general', 'writing', 'neocomplete', 'programming', 'php', 'ruby', 'python', 'javascript', 'html', 'misc',]
endif
```

Another setting in ***~/.vimrc*** is as following:

```
" neocomplete {
        if count(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'neocomplete')
            let g:acp_enableAtStartup = 0
            let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
            let g:neocomplete#enable_smart_case = 1
            let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_delimiter = 1
            let g:neocomplete#max_list = 15
            let g:neocomplete#force_overwrite_completefunc = 1
            ...
```

And then further down in ***~/.vimrc*** some key bindings as following...

```
" Define keyword.
            if !exists('g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns')
                let g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns = {}
            endif
            let g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns['default'] = '\h\w*'

            " Plugin key-mappings {
                " These two lines conflict with the default digraph mapping of <C-K>
                if !exists('g:spf13_no_neosnippet_expand')
                    imap <C-k> <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
                    smap <C-k> <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
                endif
                if exists('g:spf13_noninvasive_completion')
                    inoremap <CR> <CR>
                    " <ESC> takes you out of insert mode
                    inoremap <expr> <Esc>   pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>\<Esc>" : "\<Esc>"
                    " <CR> accepts first, then sends the <CR>
                    inoremap <expr> <CR>    pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>\<CR>" : "\<CR>"
                    " <Down> and <Up> cycle like <Tab> and <S-Tab>
                    inoremap <expr> <Down>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Down>"
                    inoremap <expr> <Up>    pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<Up>"
                    " Jump up and down the list
                    inoremap <expr> <C-d>   pumvisible() ? "\<PageDown>\<C-p>\<C-n>" : "\<C-d>"
                    inoremap <expr> <C-u>   pumvisible() ? "\<PageUp>\<C-p>\<C-n>" : "\<C-u>"
                else
                    " <C-k> Complete Snippet
                    " <C-k> Jump to next snippet point
                    imap <silent><expr><C-k> neosnippet#expandable() ?
                                \ "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : (pumvisible() ?
                                \ "\<C-e>" : "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)")
                    smap <TAB> <Right><Plug>(neosnippet_jump_or_expand)

                    inoremap <expr><C-g> neocomplete#undo_completion()
                    inoremap <expr><C-l> neocomplete#complete_common_string()
                    "inoremap <expr><CR> neocomplete#complete_common_string()

                    " <CR>: close popup
                    " <s-CR>: close popup and save indent.
                    inoremap <expr><s-CR> pumvisible() ? neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<CR>" : "\<CR>"

                    function! CleverCr()
                        if pumvisible()
                            if neosnippet#expandable()
                                let exp = "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand)"
                                return exp . neocomplete#smart_close_popup()
                            else
                                return neocomplete#smart_close_popup()
                            endif
                        else
                            return "\<CR>"
                        endif
                    endfunction

                    " <CR> close popup and save indent or expand snippet
                    imap <expr> <CR> CleverCr()
                    " <C-h>, <BS>: close popup and delete backword char.
                    inoremap <expr><BS> neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\<C-h>"
                    inoremap <expr><C-y> neocomplete#smart_close_popup()
                endif
```

So from these config pieces, it seems like neocomplete is enabled by default. However, now when I enter any document in vim and try to edit in insert mode, Backspace (on MAC) doesn't work as usual and I get error saying:

> E117: Unknown function: neocomplete#smart_close_popup
>
> E15: Invalid expression: neocomplete#smart_close_popup()."\^H"

I tried following approaches to fix it:

a)
By putting following in my ***~/.vimrc.before.local*** (notice omitted neocomplete). I don't like the approach because this completely disables neocomplete.

```
let g:spf13_bundle_groups=['general', 'writing', 'programming', 'php', 'ruby', 'python', 'scala', 'javascript', 'html', 'misc',]
```

b)
Setting following at the bottom of my ***~/.vimrc***

```
set backspace = indent,eol,start
```

This approach didn't work either.

So, I have idea maybe to put following in my ***~/.vimrc.before.local***

```
let g:spf13_noninvasive_completion = 1
```

but I don't know what autocompletions I would loose with that? Also, is there another way to fix this, or why is my spf13-vim installation unable to find
 ***neocomplete#smart_close_popup***

Answer (score 1):

It happened to be the problem with how I updated **spf13-vim**.

I did only

```
cd ~/.spf13-vim/
git pull
```

I forgot to do

```
vim +BundleInstall! +BundleClean +q
```

After doing that, **spf13-vim** re-installed some packages and installed following:

```
+ Shougo/neocomplete.vim
```

After openning new vim files I am now able to use Backspace again without problems with neocomplete.